# Copy object in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: java, google-api, google-cloud-storage, bad-request

I'm using the Java client for Google Cloud Platform to copy an object from inside a bucket to a different place in the same bucket.

To do that I followed the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/copy), but I'm getting a `GoogleJsonResponseException 404 Bad Request`:

```
class com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Required",
    "reason" : "required"
  } ],
  "message" : "Required"
}
```

This is my code:

```
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream("key.json"))
                    .createScoped(Collections.singleton(StorageScopes.CLOUD_PLATFORM));

            storageClient = new Storage.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).build();

 StorageObject newObject = new StorageObject();
            newObject.setName(newName);

            Storage.Objects.Copy request = storageClient.objects().copy(bucketName, objectName, bucketName, newName, newObject);
            request.setDestinationPredefinedAcl("publicread");

            request.execute();
```

So far this is the only operation that fails, upload, download, getLength and a few others work just fine.

**Update:**

I manage to make it work removing this line:

```
request.setDestinationPredefinedAcl("publicread");
```

Anyway I would like to know what's wrong since in the future I would like to be able to chose if the new object is public or private.

Comment: To me it looks like while calling the request, you are missing a required field or its not passed correctly.

Comment: I think the first parameter should be the Data.Object field..  'content' in the example link you provided from google site.

Comment: @lsiva thanks for your answers, I manage to partially make it work and updated the question.

Comment: There was a temporary configuration issue in GCS that interfered with body-less POST requests to the JSON API. You should be able to issue the request as stated originally now. You should also be able to omit the whole newObject and pass null, since you're not setting anything other than the name, which is provided via parameter.

Comment: If there's no change in content, then pass it as null. Copy operation will work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact error when trying to copy an object from one place to another. The solution is to set newObject as null:

```
Storage.Objects.Copy request = storageClient.objects().copy(bucketName, objectName, bucketName, newName, null);
```